# Not able to change the content of a div on click of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that has a link and content. On a click of a link i wish to change the link itself and the content inside that div

I have 2 links

```
<a href="#" class="add1> Add </a>
<a href="#" class="add2> Subtract </a>
```

What my requirement is that

> 1) By default the Add link should get displayed and along with it the content inside `<div id="addcontent1">` should get displayed under `<div id="answer">`.
>
> 2) When a user clicks on Add the data inside the `<div> id="addcontent2">` should get displayed inside `<div id="answer">`, but the Add link should get replaced by subtract link
>
> 3) When the user clicks on Subtract link the data inside `<div id="addcontent1">` should get displayed back inside `<div id="answer">` and in place of subtract link the Add link should come back

Main div

```
<div class="change">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="#" class="add1> Add </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div id="answer">Data will appear here when one of the tabs above is clicked</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Content that needs to get replaced

```
<div id="addcontent1">
    Random text will appear here
</div> 

<div id="addcontent2">
    <form action="action_page.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" >    
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you linked the correct fiddle? The code seems completely unrelated to your question. Also, please include *all* relevant code in the question

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Sorry for that have updated my post

Comment: Why are you not toggling the display of the elements? Why do you need to change the contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a kind of **toggle** event. Create `a` elemets both with contents **Subtract** and **Add** then toggle them. Second, create content objects and store them in a content list. After that, you must also create 2 functions for toggling links and contents for both clicking links and specific contents. We can use `data-*` attribute to help us doing it. Let's see the following example.

```js
// Create an Array list for storing different contents.
var contentList = [];

// The contents are within attribute 'data-of-sn' which are corresponding to the attribute 'data-sn' of links. Also you can see the children have class 'click-toggle' mean you are able to toggle just like links do.
var content1 = $(
  '<div class="add-content" data-of-sn="2">' +
    '<form action="action_page.php">' +
      '<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Can Not Toggle">' +
      '<input class="click-toggle" type="submit" value="Can Toggle">' +
    '</form>' +
  '</div>'
);

var content2 = $(
  '<div class="add-content" data-of-sn="1">' +
    '<p>Can Not Toggle</p>' +
    '<button class="click-toggle">Can Toggle</button>' +
  '</div>'
);

// Toggle link element.
function toggleLink() {
  $('.add').toggle();
}

// Toggle content by serial number.
function toggleContent(sn) {
  // The correspond index of content Array.
  var index = sn - 1;

  // Remove current content in div#answer.
  $('#answer > div').remove();

  // Append new content in div#answer.
  $('#answer').append(contentList[index]);

  // Bind click event by any element has class 'click-toggle'.
  $('.click-toggle').on('click', bindClickEvent);
}

// Bind event function.
function bindClickEvent(e) {
  // Prevent default behavior of HTML element, e.g. submit button which send form and reload page.
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get attribute 'data-of-sn' of the parent whose class name includes 'add-content'.
  var sn = $(this).parents('.add-content').eq(0).attr('data-of-sn');

  // Execute toggleLink function;
  toggleLink();

  // Execute toggleContent function by serial number of target.
  toggleContent(sn);
};

// Put the contents in the Array list.
contentList.push(content1);
contentList.push(content2);

// Bind click event with a callback function.
$('.add').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var sn = $(this).attr('data-sn');
  toggleLink();
  toggleContent(sn);
});

// Show default content.
toggleContent(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="change">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#" class="add" data-sn="1">
      <h4>Add</h4>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="add" data-sn="2" style="display:none;">
      <h4>Subtract</h4>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="new_member_box_display" id="answer">  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the toggle seems to work fine but the content is not coming properly

Comment: What html content will you put in?

Comment: By the way, I don't know what actually result you need though.

Comment: It's a common design. Try it and tell me it is you need or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try jquery append...

just like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="change">
   <div class="col-md-2">
    <a href="#" class="add"> Add </a>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-10 main-content">
   This section is for add content
 </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").click(function(){
      if ($(".add").text() == "Subtract"){
       $(".add").text("Add");
       $(".main-content").text("This section is for add content");
     }else{
       $(".add").text("Subtract");
       $(".main-content").text("This section is for subtract content");
     }
   });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the code that you gave, on clicking on add it it is changes to subtract but on clicking on subtract it is not going back to add, i want interchanging of the div

Comment: now you can check it now...this is a simple step :)

Comment: i need to pass a proper html form along with css in place of the text  can you please tell how to do so

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#lnkAdd").click(function(){
    $("#lnkAdd")[0].text="Subtract";
    $("#content")[0].innerText = "This section is for subtract content";

});
});
```

### You can use the above code as a solution. Here i have used a jquery-3.1.1.js file. You can download the jQuery file from http://jquery.com/download/. After downloaded just link the jQuery file to your HTML file and copy the above code in the script section.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are expecting.
Please feel free to modify or extend this.

```js
$("body").on("click", "a.add", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('add').addClass('subtract').html('<h4>Subtract</h4>')
    $(this).parent().next('div').text('This section is for subtract content')
});

$("body").on("click", "a.subtract", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('subtract').addClass('add').html('<h4>Add</h4>')
    $(this).parent().next('div').text('This section is for add content')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="change">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="add"><h4> Add </h4></a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-10">
       This section is for add content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seems to work fine, but the text/content that  have used is for sample, i would like to load a html form in place of content, can you please tell me how i can do so

Comment: you can pass your html in .html() function

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, with minimum change or your original code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.change a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        if( !$(this).hasClass('subtract') ){
         $(this).addClass('subtract').text('Subtract');
         $(this).parents('.change').find('div').eq(-1).text("This section is for subtract content");
        }else{
         $(this).removeClass('subtract').text('Add');
         $(this).parents('.change').find('div').eq(-1).text("This section is for add content"); 
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change">
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="#"> Add </a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-10">
       This section is for add content
   </div>
</div>
```